# Some controls wont resize with window properly, statusbar creates whitespace for no reason i understand yet

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, resize, alignment

I need to glue content to window sides, would also like to add a `gridsplitter` to resize internal control separation, and the status bar creates whitespace.
The Grid won't resize vertically with the bottom of the window for instance.
Currently, I am yet unaware of the cause or resolution, starting to go blind on the code. I could use a second pair of eyes.

Change Heights into MinHeights, use Grid containers, etc.
Pretty much anything I could find and think of, including staring down the code...

```
<Window x:Class="Teachers_Lounge.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Teachers_Lounge"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="Teachers Lounge" 
        Height="625" 
        Width="1525" 
        MinHeight="625" 
        MinWidth="1525" 

        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" 
        Closing="Window_Closing" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="265" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Name:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Date:" Foreground="DarkGray" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventDateTime}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-5,0,5,0">
                    <Button x:Name="EditEvent_Button" Width="40" Height="15" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Background="LightGray" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=OnClickEditEvent}" Click="EditEvent_Button_Click">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0, -2">Edit</TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteEvent_Button" Width="40" Height="15" Margin="0,20,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderThickness="0" Background="LightGray" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=OnClickDeleteEvent}" Click="DeleteEvent_Button_Click">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0, -2">Delete</TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid MinHeight="586" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="360" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="DateAndTime" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="dddd dd mmmm HHh" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" FontSize="20" IsEnabled="False"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="Topic" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,77,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Topic" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" KeyDown="Topic_KeyDown" LostFocus="Topic_LostFocus" />
        <Button x:Name="Settings_Button" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,10" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Settings_Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="62">Settings</Button>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
              Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="489*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Menu BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem Header="New Event" Click="NewReplacement_Click" />
            </Menu>
            <ListBox x:Name="CalendarList" Grid.Row="1"
                     BorderThickness="1 0 1 1" BorderBrush="Black"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="350" MinHeight="485" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CalendarTemplate}" KeyDown="CalendarList_KeyDown"/>
        </Grid>



        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="485" MinWidth="1072" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Menu BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem Header="" Click="ExcelPreviousDate_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="" Click="ExcelPreviousWeek_Click" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="ExcelActiveTimewindow" Header="Week XX, Date dd-MM-yy" IsEnabled="False" />
                <MenuItem Header="" Click="ExcelNextWeek_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="" Click="ExcelNextDate_Click" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="New Replacement" Click="NewReplacement_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="Delete Replacements" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="DeleteReplacements_Click" />
            </Menu>

            <DataGrid Name="ExcelDataView" Grid.Row="1"
                      BorderThickness="1 0 1 1" BorderBrush="Black"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      ColumnWidth="*"  
                      RowBackground="WhiteSmoke"  
                      Background="LightBlue"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      BeginningEdit="ExcelDataView_BeginningEdit"
                      CellEditEnding="ExcelDataView_CellEditEnding"                       
                      RowEditEnding="ExcelDataView_RowEditEnding" 
                      SelectionChanged="ExcelDataView_SelectionChanged"
                      MinWidth="1077" MinHeight="485" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnExcelHeaderClicked" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding TimeText, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="70" CanUserSort="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Replaced User" Binding="{Binding ReplacedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="140" CanUserSort="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Replacement User" Binding="{Binding ReplacementUser, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="140" CanUserSort="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class" Binding="{Binding Class, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="170" CanUserSort="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="170" CanUserSort="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Info" Binding="{Binding AdditionalInfo, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserSort="False" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Mark" Binding="{Binding Marked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserSort="False" Width="50">
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnExcelDeleteColumnChecked"/>
                                <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnExcelDeleteColumnUnchecked"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

        <Menu Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" BorderBrush="Black" IsEnabled="False"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20">
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <MenuItem MinWidth="1111" BorderThickness="0">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="StatusbarMessage" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               TextAlignment="Left" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem BorderThickness="0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Width="350" >
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="StatusbarInfo" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="335" 
                               TextAlignment="Right" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A proper layout that resizes as it should is what I'd expect.
Some weird behavior and glue-ing are what is happening though.

Comment: Have you tried putting this in a new project, and removing every single thing you can, to just reproduce the problem. in turn creating a minimal verifiable example

Comment: Not yet, i will get on that right away and get back to you, good idea.

Comment: if you _"need to glue content to window sides"_ I guess it's better to use `DockPanel` instead of `Grid`?

Comment: I tend to prefer Grids tbh, perhaps I'm missing why to go for DockPanels ? BTW thanks *TheGeneral*.. that fixed it ! The glue problem was simple: Stretch Alignments, and no Heights or Widhts, Thanks

Comment: Answer: As *TheGeneral* pointed out, starting over and reproducing the problem with minimal content was a very good way of going about things.
Figured out that simply removing all Sizes from the content, so delete Width and Height properties, and changing the Alignment properties to the value "Stretch" completely fixed all the issues.